# Can I have two or more <router-outlet> in Angular?

Tags: angular, routes, router

I want to have two `<router-outlet>` in my Angular app, example in scheme below. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In the version 2 or above, for using multiple router-outlet in the same template you need  to specify children element in the RouterModule.forRoot structure.

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AnotherPageComponent } from './anotherpage.component';
    import { AnotherPageSubComponent1 } from './anotherpagesubcomponent1.component';
    import { AnotherPageSubComponent2 } from './anotherpagesubcomponent2.component';

@Component({ 
    template: `
    <h1>Angular Router</h1>
    <nav> <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active"> Home </a>
          <a routerLink="/anotherpage" routerLinkActive="active"> Another page </a>
          <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active"> About </a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> `
})

export class AppComponent {}
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: "", component: HomeComponent, data: { title: "Home" } },
            { path: "home", component: HomeComponent, },
            { path: "anotherpage", component: AnotherPageComponent,
                children:
                [ 
                    { path: "", redirectTo: "anotherpagesubcomponent1", pathMatch: "full" },
                    { path: "anotherpagesubcomponent1", component: AnotherPageSubComponent1,
                    { path: "anotherpagesubcomponent2", component: AnotherPageSubComponent2
                ]
            },
            { path: "about", component: AboutComponent,
        ])
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]})
```

**anotherpage.component.ts** (is your page1)

```
@Component({
    template: `
    <h2>Angular Router on Another Page</h2>
    <nav>
        <a routerLink="/anotherpagesubcomponent1" routerLinkActive="active"> Another page sub component 1</a>
        <a routerLink="/anotherpagesubcomponent2" routerLinkActive="active"> Another page sub component 2</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})

export class AnotherPageComponent {}
```

Let me know if it's clear.